# Anova test for GLM in python

Tags: python, statistics, glm, statsmodels

I am trying to get the F-statistic and p-value for each of the covariates in GLM. In Python I am using the stats mode.formula.api to conduct the GLM.

```
formula = 'PropNo_Pred ~ Geography + log10BMI + Cat_OpCavity + CatLes_neles + CatRural_urban + \
        CatPred_Control + CatNative_Intro + Midpoint_of_study'

mod1 = smf.glm(formula=formula, data=A2, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
mod1.summary()
```

After that I am trying to do the ANOVA test for this model using the anova in statsmodels.stats

```
table1 = anova_lm(mod3)
print table1
```

However I am getting an error saying:
    'GLMResults' object has no attribute 'ssr'

Looks like this anova_lm function only applies to linear model is there a module in python that does anova test for GLMs?

Comment: a preliminary answer for ANOVA type 3 kind of result https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/qQxWdSi_fQk/0O3eAgINYhkJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, unfortunately. However, you can roll your own by using the model's hypothesis testing methods on each of the terms. In fact, some of their [ANOVA methods](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/anova.py#L144) do not even use the attribute `ssr` (which is the model's sum of squared residuals, thus obviously undefined for a binomial GLM). You could probably modify this code to do a GLM ANOVA.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add an example of how to use the hypothesis testing methods for the data in the experiment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my attempt to roll your own.

The F-statistic for nested models is defined as:

`(D_s  - D_b ) / (addtl_parameters * phi_b)`

Where:

- `D_s` is deviance of small model
- `D_b` is deviance of larger ("big)" model
- `addtl_parameters` is the difference in degrees of freedom between models.
- `phi_b` is the estimate of dispersion parameter for the larger model'

"Statistical theory says that the F-statistic
follows an F distribution, with a numerator degrees of freedom equal to the number of
added parameters and a denominator degrees of freedom equal to `n - p_b`, or the number
of records minus the number of parameters in the big model."

We translate this into code with:

```
from scipy import stats

def calculate_nested_f_statistic(small_model, big_model):
    """Given two fitted GLMs, the larger of which contains the parameter space of the smaller, return the F Stat and P value corresponding to the larger model adding explanatory power"""
    addtl_params = big_model.df_model - small_model.df_model
    f_stat = (small_model.deviance - big_model.deviance) / (addtl_params * big_model.scale)
    df_numerator = addtl_params
    # use fitted values to obtain n_obs from model object:
    df_denom = (big_model.fittedvalues.shape[0] - big_model.df_model)
    p_value = stats.f.sf(f_stat, df_numerator, df_denom)
    return (f_stat, p_value)
```

Here is a reproducible example, following the gamma GLM example in statsmodels (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
data2 = sm.datasets.scotland.load()
data2.exog = sm.add_constant(data2.exog, prepend=False)

big_model = sm.GLM(data2.endog, data2.exog, family=sm.families.Gamma()).fit()
# Drop one covariate (column):
smaller_model = sm.GLM(data2.endog, data2.exog[:, 1:], family=sm.families.Gamma()).fit()

# Using function defined in answer:
calculate_nested_f_statistic(smaller_model, big_model)
# (9.519052917304652, 0.004914748992474178)
```

Source:
https://www.casact.org/pubs/monographs/papers/05-Goldburd-Khare-Tevet.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer but i think there is a small finger mistake the function should be

```
def calculate_nested_f_statistic(small_model, big_model):

"""Given two fitted GLMs, the larger of which contains the parameter space of the smaller, return the F Stat and P value corresponding to the larger model adding explanatory power"""

   addtl_params = small_model.df_model - big_model.df_model 

   f_stat = (small_model.deviance - big_model.deviance) / (addtl_params * big_model.scale)

   df_numerator = addtl_params

   # use fitted values to obtain n_obs from model object:

   df_denom = (big_model.fittedvalues.shape[0] - big_model.df_model)

   p_value = stats.f.sf(f_stat, df_numerator, df_denom)

   return (f_stat, p_value)
```

Comment: did you run this? this should raise an exception

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Comment: Yes i run it but i ll again later, the answer aboce was good I just inversed the 2 parts of the equation inin addtl_param