# Statsmodels Anova for logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, anova

I found the `statsmodels` implementation of the anova testing for linear models to be very useful (http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm.html#statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm) but I was wondering, since it's not present in the library, how one could approach building the equivalent version for the logistic regression part.

*formulas*:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols, logit
import statsmodels.api as sm

ols(formula_str, data=data_on_which_to_perform_analysis).fit()
logit(formula_str, data=data_on_which_to_perform_analysis).fit()

sm.stats.anova_lm()
```

which means essentially (by looking at the source code) replicating `anova_single`. has anyone already done this meaybe in some remote repository? I ask because the imlementation goes very fast and very deep into the `statsmodels` core library so it's not so easy to work around it (at least with my current level of skill)

any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: I believe rmstmppr awsered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328623/anova-test-for-glm-in-python/60769343#60769343)