# Is there python function for comparing two or more Logistic Regression models using anova?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, anova

I am trying to implement the Python version of this 'R' code to compare 2 or more Logistic Regression models by finding deviance statistics

```
anova(LogisticModel.1, LogisticModel.2)
```

which gives an output like this  [image]

There is an [statsmodels](/questions/tagged/statsmodels) implementation of anova testing for linear models which work as follows:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm

m01 = ols('sales~adverts', data=df).fit()
m02 = ols('sales~adverts+airplay', data=df).fit()
m03 = ols('sales~adverts+airplay+attract', data=df).fit()
anovaResults = anova_lm(m01, m02, m03)
print(anovaResults)
```

which gives an output like
[image]

I have calculated the residual df, residual deviance , Deviance described in the Logistic Regression  table  by doing manual calculations, but I wonder if there is anything to do this automatically in Python using any Library.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819504/statsmodels-anova-for-logistic-regression) but it remains unanswered .

Comment: I believe rmstmppr awsered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328623/anova-test-for-glm-in-python/60769343#60769343)